# FTDI Cable to bypass USB for Arduino (Blend Micro) Programming

Tags: sketch, arduino-micro, ftdi

I bought a Blend Micro (an Arduino Micro with Bluetooth) a few months ago, and after my first experimentation with uploading the Blink sketch something went wrong with the USB connection--it would supply power, but no computer (Windows, OS X or Linux) would show it as a USB device, and Windows would complain that the device was somehow damaged. Anyway, when I plug the board in, it still boots up and runs "Blink" so I'd like to try to still use it.

I have a USB-to-FTDI cable, and it would seem fairly straight-forward to use that, but I'm a little uncertain to the appropriate wiring and whether I would need to tell the Arduino software somehow that I was using FTDI.

I can figure out these connections: (I think)

- black to ground
- red to 5V (VIN?)
- orange to RX
- yellow to TX

What about green and brown? Do one of those go to RST (Brown?) and MOSI (Green?)

I figured I would ask before accidentally burning something out.

Comment: A little more information as I've been Googling and reading. First of all, my FTDI cable is a Digi TTL-232R-3V3, so the wire colors are: black=GND, brown=CTS, red=VCC, orange=TX, yellow=RX, red=RTS. Looking at an [Adafruit article](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-bluefruit-ez-link/arduino-programming) I wonder if I'm out-of-luck in the Blend Micro being Leonardo-based and having USB managed inside the chip rather than using USB-to-serial on the board.

Comment: You could try re-flashing the bootloader using another arduino as ISP.

Comment: I'm afraid (a) that's a bit beyond by beginning experience, and (b) I think that would require on a Micro those six headers in the middle of the board, but those aren't exposed in the blend micro because the space is used by the Bluetooth chip. If booloader re-flashing can be done using the standard pinouts along the edges, can someone point me to a reference as a starting point?

Comment: You should be able to recover a Leonard-type board by putting it into DFU mode.

Comment: The six pin header is just for convenience. The same pins are also broken out on the side.